# Results IOrderedEnumerable is null outside context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm learning entity framework and hitting a wall. Here is my code:

```
public IOrderedEnumerable<ArchiveProcess> getHistory()
{
    using (ArchiveVMADDatabase.ArchiveDatabaseModel dataContext = new ArchiveDatabaseModel())
    {
        var query = (from history in dataContext.ArchiveProcess.AsNoTracking()
                     orderby history.ArchiveBegin descending
                     select history).Take(10).ToList();

        return query as IOrderedEnumerable<ArchiveProcess>;
    }
}
```

When I step through this code, `query` is a `List<ArchiveProcess>` containing my ten desired results. However, as soon as I exit the method and the context is disposed of, `query` becomes null. How can I avoid this? I tried doing this instead:

```
select new ArchiveProcess
{
    ArchiveBegin = history.ArchiveBegin,
    ArchiveEnd = history.ArchiveEnd,
    DeploysHistoryCount = history.DeploysHistoryCount,
    MachinesHistory = history.MachinesHistory,
    ScriptHistory = history.ScriptHistory
}
```

But then I received a `NotSupportedException`. Why does entity framework delete my precious entities as soon as the context is disposed of and how do I tell it to stop?

Comment: @willaien OP is calling `.ToList()` already

Comment: Try calling `.AsEnumerable()` instead of `.ToList()`. Same effect in terms of executing the query, but you're not losing the properties of the query (which is where, I'm assuming, you're getting null going from `List<T>` ->`IOrderedEnumerable<T>`)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer He's also trying to cast it as `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, which `List<T>` doesn't implement. He should actually just return `query`

Comment: *as soon as I exit the method* I don't see a method, so I don't know what you expect to return from it.

Comment: @GertArnold I'll update my answer. When I said, _exit the method_, I meant process the next instruction after `return query ...`.

Comment: @willaien That is the answer. If I try the cast it in the first statement rather than at the return, it's null at the return. If you submit that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query as IOrderedEnumerable<ArchiveProcess>;
```

`query` is a `List<ArchiveProcess>`, `as` returns `null` when you try use it to cast something to an interface it doesn't implement. `List<ArchiveProcess>` is not an `IOrderedEnumerable<ArchiveProcess>` so `query as IOrderedEnumerable<ArchiveProcess>` is `null`.

The only thing that `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` does that `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't do, is implement `CreateOrderedEnumerable<TKey>`, which can be called directly or through `ThenBy` and `ThenByDescending`, so you can add a secondary sort on the enumerable that only affects items considered equivalent by the earlier sort.

If you don't use `CreateOrderedEnumerable()` either directly or through `ThenBy()` or `ThenByDescending()` then change to not attempt to use it:

```
public IEnumerable<ArchiveProcess> getHistory()
{
  using (ArchiveVMADDatabase.ArchiveDatabaseModel dataContext = new ArchiveDatabaseModel())
  {
    return (from history in dataContext.ArchiveProcess.AsNoTracking()
                 orderby history.ArchiveBegin descending
                 select history).Take(10).ToList();
  }
}
```

Otherwise reapply the ordering, so that `ThenBy` etc. can be used with it:

```
public IOrderedEnumerable<ArchiveProcess> getHistory()
{
  using (ArchiveVMADDatabase.ArchiveDatabaseModel dataContext = new ArchiveDatabaseModel())
  {
    return (from history in dataContext.ArchiveProcess.AsNoTracking()
                 orderby history.ArchiveBegin descending
                 select history).Take(10).ToList().OrderBy(h => h.ArchiveBegin);
  }
}
```

However this adds a bit more overhead, so don't do it if you don't need it.

Remember, `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` is not just an ordered enumerable (all enumerables are in some order, however arbitrary), it's an ordered enumerable that has knowledge about the way it which it is ordered so as to provide for secondary sorting. If you don't need that then you don't need `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are several ways to avoid this but in general you should know precisely how long you want your context to live. In general it's better to have the using statement wrapped through the entire  method.

In order to avoid the garbage collection you can do something like this: set the object in memory and then add value to that object.

```
List<ArchiveProcess> query;
using (ArchiveVMADDatabase.ArchiveDatabaseModel dataContext = new ArchiveDatabaseModel())
{
     query = (from history in dataContext.ArchiveProcess.AsNoTracking()
                 orderby history.ArchiveBegin descending
                 select history).Take(10).ToList();

    return query; /// you do not really need to all enumerable  as IOrderedEnumerable<ArchiveProcess>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  using (ArchiveVMADDatabase.ArchiveDatabaseModel dataContext = new ArchiveDatabaseModel())
    {

       var query = dataContext.ArchiveProcess.AsNoTracking().Take(10).OrderBy(o=> o.ArchiveBegin);

        return query;
    }
```